# What's the required compressive strength and density for a material out of which to build a pyramid of a given angle and height?

Tags: classical-mechanics, material-science, building-physics

I've got a pyramid (really a wall with inclined edges), that for our purposes is infinite in length. It is 1 kilometre high, and the edges have an internal angle of 60 degrees. Here's a cross-section:

[image: Diagram]

What I want to know is what to build this thing out of, in order to have it support its own weight and not collapse. There's a concrete case for a fictional setting I'm designing: and I want to know if I can build this out of granite, with a density of 2.7 g/cm^3 and a compressive strength of 200 MPa. I think it should be feasible, given that there's mountains made out of granite with this sorta shape, but then my follow-up question would be the maximum feasible steepness of the sides given that material's limitations.

Therefore, I would ideally want a single equation including the variables of height, angle, compressive strength and density - making it reusable if I want to make the structure smaller or with a different shape (both sides of the wall would have the same angle), or change the material. Of course, it's also very possible that there's one or more variables I'm overlooking. I hope I made the idea clear at least.

Comment: I think it needs to have shear strength. Eg., jello has good compressive strength but but not much shear strength.

Comment: @KeithMcClary Good point. I do not really know all the correct terms involved; and an estimation would serve my problem well enough.

Comment: I found [this](http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu/pdf/1981JApA....2..165S). Maybe engineering.SE would know this stuff.

Comment: Thank you! That might just do it actually. And if not I will visit the site you suggested. I was thinking whether I might not be on the right SE after all...